# Migrate SSL certificate from CPanel to DigitalOcean Apache server

Tags: apache, ssl, https

This is my first time setting up HTTPS (2016. Scary, I know) and I am having trouble migrating a certificate from a server running CPanel.

There seems to be no Export button so I assume I can create myself an SSL certificate simply by copying the different keys I have: 
[image]
Unfortunately I dont know how the file should be saved (I assume as *.domain.com.crt as mentioned in [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority). Yet I see they need other certificates (such as intermediate cert). Anothe unfortunality is that the site was hosted and run by an external manager so I dont have root access to export the ssl certificate using CLI.

How can I get around this?

Do I have to buy a new certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying an SSL from server to server is, sadly, no easy matter. The SSL was generated from a CSR specific to the server itself, so it is very likely the SSL certificate itself is not valid on the new server.

If the SSL was self-signed, you can just make a new one on the new server using this command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt
```

If it was a SSL you paid for, contact the SSL provider to work with them to regenerate it for the new server.

Alternatively, you can use [cert-bot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to make a whole new SSL on the new server pretty quickly.